# GIMP: Setting default DPI when creating an image from clipboard

Tags: clipboard, gimp, dpi

Is there a way to change the default DPI when creating an image from clipboard? On my old version of GIMP, it used to be 300 DPI, which I quite liked. After updating GIMP, it creates images from the clipboard at 72 DPI. Is there a way to change that setting without manually changing the print size every time I create an image from the clipoard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on your settings. Please check the advanced settings in the **Create a New Image** dialog.

If 72 dpi is set there, then an image from the clipboard will also be pasted with this value for pixels per inch.

Set the value for a new image to 300 dpi according to your requirements and create a new image e.g. with a transparent background. Paste an image from the clipboard as a test.

GIMP will save the last setting for you.

The screenshot below (GIMP version 2.10.20) shows the dialogs.

[image]